# How can I copy a list of class attributes as a CSS selector from Chrome's Elements tab?

Tags: copy-paste, google-chrome-devtools

I'm copy/pasting a lot of class attributes from the HTML of a web page from the Elements tab in the Chrome Dev Tools like

```html
<label class="s-label mb4 d-block" for="wmd-input">
```

to use them as CSS selectors

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".s-label.mb4.d-block")
```

Manually adding those dots `.` is tedious and error-prone. Is there something I can do to automate this? When I right click and "copy as selector" I get something useless like `#post-editor > div.ps-relative > label`.

Answer (score 1):

You could download a clipboard manager like ClipboardFusion, https://www.clipboardfusion.com/Download/.

In ClipboardFusion, create a macro that adds double quotes and a dot and then assign a shortcut to the macro. Then just copy the selector, enter the shortcut command, and then paste.

The macros are written in C# - this one does what you wish (copied from the macro editor in ClipboardFusion):

```
// The 'text' parameter will contain the text from the:
//   - Current Clipboard when run by HotKey
//   - History Item when run from the History Menu
// The returned string will be:
//   - Placed directly on the Clipboard
//   - Ignored by ClipboardFusion if it is 'null'
public static class ClipboardFusionHelper
{
    public static string ProcessText(string text)
    {
        // your code goes here
        return "\"." + text + "\"";
    }
}
```